# read csv file from Data folder

Tags: android, csv, storage

I use the following to read a csv file into an array from a file in the assets folder

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("Buttons.csv")));
```

How do i change it so it reads it from the data/data folder

Comment: `so it reads it from the data/data folder` - You **can't**. Since you can't place your stuff in the `/data/data/your.app.name/` folder. You have the `/assets/...` and the `/res/raw/` for putting your files in. Or you can use the external storage.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: i need to be able to read and write to the file Im told you cant write to the assets folder so I copy the file from the assets folder to the dta/data so i can then read and write to it I donto want to write to sd card as some people dont have sd cards and I cant get it working on the phones internal memory

Comment: @user3422687 : If you search Stack Overflow there are questions relating to copying a file from assets to internal memory.

Comment: I did search and have worked out how to copy the file i need to work out how to read and write to the file in the new position

Answer (score 0):

```
Csvreader csvreader = new CSVReader(openFileInput("Buttons.csv"));
```

By the way: this reads from folder

```
/data/data/packagename/files
```